# Git In-Memory repository update target

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'm still fairly new to the whole libgit2 and libgit2sharp codebases, but I've been trying to tackle the issue of In-Memory repositories and Refdb storage of references.

I've gotten everything almost working in my new [branch](https://github.com/theit8514/libgit2sharp/tree/refdb-rewrite):

1. Create the In-Memory repository and attach Refdb and Odb instance to it.
2. Create initial commit and set the reference for refs/heads/master.
3. Create the second commit...

The problem I run into now is updating refs/heads/master to the second commit. The UpdateTarget call to refs/heads/master runs into an error in git_reference_set_target:

```
LibGit2Sharp.NameConflictException : config value 'user.name' was not found
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result) in \libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Ensure.cs:line 154
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.ZeroResult(Int32 result) in \libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Ensure.cs:line 172
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_reference_set_target(ReferenceHandle reference, ObjectId id, String logMessage) in \libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Proxy.cs:line 2042
   at LibGit2Sharp.ReferenceCollection.UpdateDirectReferenceTarget(Reference directRef, ObjectId targetId, String logMessage) in \libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\ReferenceCollection.cs:line 476
   at LibGit2Sharp.ReferenceCollection.UpdateTarget(Reference directRef, ObjectId targetId, String logMessage) in \libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\ReferenceCollection.cs:line 470
   at LibGit2Sharp.ReferenceCollection.UpdateTarget(Reference directRef, String objectish, String logMessage) in \libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\ReferenceCollection.cs:line 498
   at LibGit2Sharp.ReferenceCollection.UpdateTarget(String name, String canonicalRefNameOrObjectish, String logMessage) in \libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\ReferenceCollection.cs:line 534
   at LibGit2Sharp.ReferenceCollection.UpdateTarget(String name, String canonicalRefNameOrObjectish) in \libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\ReferenceCollection.cs:line 565
   at LibGit2Sharp.Tests.RepositoryFixture.CanCreateInMemoryRepositoryWithBackends() in \libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp.Tests\RepositoryFixture.cs:line 791
```

I have not been able to debug down into the libgit2 level, but from what I can tell the issue is in [git_reference_create_matching call to git_reference__log_signature](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/90500d81dcb04ae3bdaf0f6211ca8754d9425b70/src/refs.c#L507).

Is there a call I am missing that can update a reference in a Bare repo that doesn't require a signature? If any libgit2 guys know of how to do this in libgit2, I can implement it on the C# side.

As a test, I created two [unit tests](https://github.com/theit8514/libgit2sharp/commit/b78352f90b61026c7a064e35b1f5b6203d3af721#diff-7f117c1da35042f14dd81201b7fa4bdaR727) that perform the same actions In-Memory and on disk, and the In-Memory fails when calling UpdateTarget after creating the second commit. This follows the code on the [wiki](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/Git-commit):

```
    private Commit CreateCommit(Repository repository, string fileName, string content, string message = null)
    {
        if (message == null)
        {
            message = "i'm a commit message :)";
        }

        Blob newBlob = repository.ObjectDatabase.CreateBlobFromContent(content);

        // Put the blob in a tree
        TreeDefinition td = new TreeDefinition();
        td.Add(fileName, newBlob, Mode.NonExecutableFile);
        Tree tree = repository.ObjectDatabase.CreateTree(td);

        // Committer and author
        Signature committer = new Signature("Auser", "auser@example.com", DateTime.Now);
        Signature author = committer;

        // Create binary stream from the text
        return repository.ObjectDatabase.CreateCommit(
            author,
            committer,
            message,
            tree,
            repository.Commits,
            true);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CanCreateRepositoryWithoutBackends()
    {
        SelfCleaningDirectory scd = BuildSelfCleaningDirectory();

        Repository.Init(scd.RootedDirectoryPath, true);
        ObjectId commit1Id;
        using (var repository = new Repository(scd.RootedDirectoryPath))
        {
            Commit commit1 = CreateCommit(repository, "filePath.txt", "Hello commit 1!");
            commit1Id = commit1.Id;
            repository.Refs.Add("refs/heads/master", commit1.Id);
            Assert.Equal(1, repository.Commits.Count());
            Assert.NotNull(repository.Refs.Head);
            Assert.Equal(1, repository.Refs.Count());
        }

        using (var repository = new Repository(scd.RootedDirectoryPath))
        {
            Commit commit2 = CreateCommit(repository, "filePath.txt", "Hello commit 2!");
            Assert.Equal(commit1Id, commit2.Parents.First().Id);

            repository.Refs.UpdateTarget("refs/heads/master", commit2.Sha);
            Assert.Equal(2, repository.Commits.Count());
            Assert.Equal(1, repository.Refs.Count());
            Assert.NotNull(repository.Refs.Head);
            Assert.Equal(commit2.Sha, repository.Refs.Head.ResolveToDirectReference().TargetIdentifier);
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CanCreateInMemoryRepositoryWithBackends()
    {
        OdbBackendFixture.MockOdbBackend odbBackend = new OdbBackendFixture.MockOdbBackend();
        RefdbBackendFixture.MockRefdbBackend refdbBackend = new RefdbBackendFixture.MockRefdbBackend();

        ObjectId commit1Id;
        using (var repository = new Repository())
        {
            repository.Refs.SetBackend(refdbBackend);
            repository.ObjectDatabase.AddBackend(odbBackend, 5);

            Commit commit1 = CreateCommit(repository, "filePath.txt", "Hello commit 1!");
            commit1Id = commit1.Id;
            repository.Refs.Add("refs/heads/master", commit1.Id);
            Assert.Equal(1, repository.Commits.Count());
            Assert.NotNull(repository.Refs.Head);
            Assert.Equal(commit1.Sha, repository.Refs.Head.ResolveToDirectReference().TargetIdentifier);

            // Emulating Git, repository.Refs enumerable does not include the HEAD.
            // Thus, repository.Refs.Count will be 1 and refdbBackend.References.Count will be 2.
            Assert.Equal(1, repository.Refs.Count());
            Assert.Equal(2, refdbBackend.References.Count);
        }

        using (var repository = new Repository())
        {
            repository.Refs.SetBackend(refdbBackend);
            repository.ObjectDatabase.AddBackend(odbBackend, 5);

            Commit commit2 = CreateCommit(repository, "filePath.txt", "Hello commit 2!");
            Assert.Equal(commit1Id, commit2.Parents.First().Id);
            //repository.Refs.UpdateTarget(repository.Refs["refs/heads/master"], commit2.Id);

            //var master = repository.Refs["refs/heads/master"];
            //Assert.Equal(commit1Id.Sha, master.TargetIdentifier);
            repository.Refs.UpdateTarget("refs/heads/master", commit2.Sha); // fails at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_reference_set_target(ReferenceHandle reference, ObjectId id, String logMessage)
            //repository.Refs.Add("refs/heads/master", commit2.Id); // fails at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_reference_create(RepositoryHandle repo, String name, ObjectId targetId, Boolean allowOverwrite, String logMessage)
            Assert.Equal(2, repository.Commits.Count());
            Assert.Equal(1, repository.Refs.Count());
            Assert.NotNull(repository.Refs.Head);
            Assert.Equal(commit2.Sha, repository.Refs.Head.ResolveToDirectReference().TargetIdentifier);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I double checked that the On-Disk repository does not have config for user.name or user.email in the test, and it does not seem to be inheriting from my global git config. Regardless, the call to git_reference_create and git_reference_set_target succeed with On-Disk and fail with In-Memory.